# Primefaces : <p:ajax inside of DataTable calls method several times after I update the dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

The problem is with "p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{companyBean.update()}" ... ", when i doubleClick for the first time, the method "update()" is called one time (Perfect !), but after that when i press on the commandButton "button1" and i doubleClick on the component again , the "update()" is called 2 times. When i repeat one more time, the "update()" is called 3 times ... ... ... ...
This is very weird !! I think when i update the datatable with the commandButton, the ajax event keeps the upgrade for itself. I dont know (?) ... Could anyone help me to solve it ??

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="5">
  <p:commandButton id="button1"  value="Search" actionListener="#{                     
     companyBean.search()}" update="dataTable"/>          
</h:panelGrid>
```

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="companyTO" value="#{companyBean.companiesTO}"                      
  selection="#companyBean.selectedCompanyTO}" rowKey="#{companyTO}"                   
  emptyMessage="" selectionMode="single" >   

 <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{companyBean.update()}" immediate="true"   
        process="@this" />

 <p:column >

     ...
<p:dataTable>
```

obs.: When i remove the "update="dataTable", the "event="rowDblselect"" works perfect, call the method only one time. So, the problem is on the update.

I found the same problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904556/updating-datatable-with-own-datamodel-calls-method-more-and-more

Comment: Take a look to your generated html code. Probably you have more than a call to the method. What are you exactly doing in `companyBean.search()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `immediate` attribute of your `ajax` event and in your `commandbutton` add the attributes:

```
process="@this" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true"
```

Somethig like this:

Event:

```
   <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{companyBean.update()}" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />
```

Button:

```
 <p:commandButton id="button1"  value="Search" actionListener="#{                     
         companyBean.search()}" update="dataTable" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true"/>
```